# Does node.replaceData() work in GTM tags? Have the right steps identified in Console, but GTM tag isn't editing on-page content

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-tag-manager

Essentially, I would like to querySelect a specific text node on the page and replace that node's textContent/data.  I have successfully done this via Chrome Console, but when I try to replicate the steps in Tag Manager, I'm seeing nothing happen.

Here is the structure of the relevant portion:[image]

The phone number I need to replace is blacked out.  As you can see, I can querySelect this by targeting `span.telephone b` and then the second childNode.

Here is the node tree for the `b` element:

[image]

The steps I went through in the Console were...

```
 var ogtel = document.body.querySelector("span.telephone b");

var split = ogtel.childNodes[1];

split.textContent;
" (555) 555-5555"

split.replaceData(0,15," new telly baby");
```

But when I fire a Custom HTML tag in GTM that does the same thing, it shows the tag successfully firing, but that number on the page isn't replace in preview mode.

Here's that Custom HTML tag script. I tried replaceData() and deleteData()...

```
<script> ( function () {
    
var ogtel = document.body.querySelector("span.telephone b");
    
var tel = ogtel.childNodes[1];

var tel2 = tel.deleteData(0,15);

  
          
          }  ) </script>
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?  Can GTM even select/edit/delete text data within nodes like this?

Answer (score 1):

ANSWERED!

I wasn't activating the function (like an idiot...)

New GTM code that works..

```
<script> function changeTel() {
    
var ogtel = document.body.querySelector("span.telephone b");
    
var tel = ogtel.childNodes[1];

var tel2 = tel.deleteData(0,15);
          
          }  
  
change = changeTel();
  
   </script>
```